# Compile time operations on types

Tags: rust, types, compile-time

I'm reworking my ECS from the ground up, and went for archetypes this time.

The core idea of the archetypal ECS is that I have a map that binds archetypes (tuple of component types) ids to buckets containing all entities of that archetype (and so the components data).

What I want:

I though about my entity being generic over their archetype, to have compile time knowledge about what components each entity have, and guarantee the result of the `get_component` method.

```
pub struct Entity<Archetype> {
    archetype_marker: PhantomData<Archetype>,
    index: usize,
}
```

With Rust types, I was thinking that archetypes should be straight up tuples of types, as it is what makes the most sense. For example, `(String, usize, u32)` is an archetype. Ids can be computed with [TypeId](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html).

I already have a basic structure:

```
struct ComponentTable {
    // for each archetype, store the entities components.
    components: ArchetypeMap,
}

struct ComponentBucket<Archetype> {
    entities: HashMap<usize, Archetype>,
    last_index: usize,
}
```

The `ArchetypeMap` is a map similar to [the AnyMap crate](https://docs.rs/anymap/latest/anymap/), where I map `Archetype` to `ComponentBucket<Archetype>` except I enforce values in the mapp implement the `AbstractBucket` trait:

```
pub trait AbstractBucket {
    fn query<Archetype>(&self) -> Option<impl Iterator<Type = Archetype>>;
}
```

The goal here was to be able to iterate over all buckets for iteration, even with the type ereasure provided by the archetype map.

Now, ECS need to be able to create / remove entities, which is trivial with this method.

```
impl ComponentTable {
    pub fn create_entity<Archetype: 'static>(&mut self, components: Archetype) -> Entity<Archetype> {
        match self.components.get_mut::<ComponentBucket<Archetype>>() {
            Some(bucket) => bucket.create_entity(components),
            None => {
                let mut bucket = ComponentBucket::default();
                let entity = bucket.create_entity(components);
                self.components.insert::<ComponentBucket<Archetype>>(bucket);
                entity
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn remove_entity<Archetype: 'static>(&mut self, entity: Entity<Archetype>) -> Option<Archetype> {
        self.components.get_mut::<ComponentBucket<Archetype>>()?.remove_entity(entity)
    }
}

impl<Archetype> ComponentBucket<Archetype> {
    pub fn create_entity(&mut self, components: Archetype) -> Entity<Archetype> {
        let index = self.last_index;
        self.last_index += 1;
        self.entities.insert(index, components);
        Entity::new(index)
    }

    pub fn remove_entity(&mut self, entity: Entity<Archetype>) -> Option<Archetype> {
        self.entities.remove(&entity.index())
    }
}
```

Adding / removing components could be done by being explicit about the full archetype tuple, but I would rather have a method that works on every archetype, as this implementation will require having lots of different names depending on the archetype size of the entity:

```
impl ComponentTable {
    pub fn add_component<T1: 'static, T2: 'static, C: 'static>(&mut self, entity: Entity<(T1, T2)>, component: C) -> Option<Entity<(T1, T2, C)>> {
        let archetype = self.remove_entity(entity)?;
        let new_entity = self.create_entity((archetype.0, archetype.1, component));
        Some(new_entity)
    }

    pub fn remove_component<T1: 'static, T2: 'static, C: 'static>(&mut self, entity: Entity<(T1, T2, C)>) -> Option<Entity<(T1, T2)>> {
        let archetype = self.remove_entity(entity)?;
        let new_entity = self.create_entity((archetype.0, archetype.1));
        Some(new_entity)
    }
}
```

Now this is where I'm stuck, trying to implement the `AbstractBucket` trait for my buckets:

```
impl<BucketArchetype> AbstractBucket for ComponentBucket<BucketArchetype> {
    fn query<Archetype>(&self) -> Option<()> {
        // ???? 
    }
}
```

How could I have ways to 'unpack' the types as tuple of types ? it looks like it does not make sense, as my types arn't necessarly tuples, but if they are not we can consider them as tuple of one element.

This function should:
if the `Archetype` is a sub archetype of the `BucketArchetype`, return an iterator over the archetype (with a mapping from the bucket archetype to the asked archetype). Otherwise, return `None`.

With Rust's powerful type system, I feel like what I'm trying to achieve is doable, but I'm failing to either build it, or find some example of something the compiler could not understand and prove my design can not work.

I've looked at examples of existing archetypal ECS, but they all seems to keep archetypes value at run time, where I'm trying to do most of the work at compile time.

I've also looked into variadic generics, as this looks like it would be a good fit, but they are not available in Rust.

In the end, I'm trying to perform operations on types at compile time, like adding types to type tuples and building new types this way. This looks like operations that are doable at compile time, but I'm struggling with it. Maybe Rust is not powerful enough ? Maybe I need some more powerful architecture for my archetype system ?

Answer (score 0):

> if the Archetype is a sub archetype of the BucketArchetype, return an
> iterator over the archetype (with a mapping from the bucket archetype
> to the asked archetype). Otherwise, return None.

This sounds like you may want to express a bound on the ability to create the Archetype: From, perhaps like:

ecs_contract.rs :

```rs
pub struct Entity<Archetype> {
    archetype_marker: PhantomData<Archetype>,
    index: usize,
}

struct ComponentTable {
    // for each archetype, store the entities components.
    components: ArchetypeMap, // you must clarify this type!
}

struct ComponentBucket<Archetype> {
    entities: HashMap<usize, Archetype>,
    last_index: usize,
}

// functionalize the entities to enable more sensible default impl of AbstractBucket
pub trait Entities<A> {
    fn entities(&self) -> HashMap<usize, A>;
}

// note: you probably want to use lifetimes to avoid cloning your underlying bucket data to make this iterator (assuming sub archetypes are subsets of archetypes)
pub trait AbstractBucket<BucketArchetype>: Entities<BucketArchetype> {
    fn query<Archetype>(&self) -> Option<impl Iterator<Type = Archetype>>
    where Archetype: From<BucketArchetype> {
    Some(self.entities().values().map(Archetype::from))
   }
}
```

ecs_impls.rs :

```rs
impl ComponentTable {
    pub fn create_entity<Archetype: 'static>(&mut self, components: Archetype) -> Entity<Archetype> {
        match self.components.get_mut::<ComponentBucket<Archetype>>() {
            Some(bucket) => bucket.create_entity(components),
            None => {
                let mut bucket = ComponentBucket::default();
                let entity = bucket.create_entity(components);
                self.components.insert::<ComponentBucket<Archetype>>(bucket);
                entity
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn remove_entity<Archetype: 'static>(&mut self, entity: Entity<Archetype>) -> Option<Archetype> {
        self.components.get_mut::<ComponentBucket<Archetype>>()?.remove_entity(entity)
    }
}

impl<Archetype> ComponentBucket<Archetype> {
    pub fn create_entity(&mut self, components: Archetype) -> Entity<Archetype> {
        let index = self.last_index;
        self.last_index += 1;
        self.entities.insert(index, components);
        Entity::new(index)
    }

    pub fn remove_entity(&mut self, entity: Entity<Archetype>) -> Option<Archetype> {
        self.entities.remove(&entity.index())
    }
}

// default implementation
impl<BucketArchetype> AbstractBucket for ComponentBucket<BucketArchetype> {}
```

To hold multiple kinds of archetype, you might want to make a nested structure wherein ComponentTable holds a hashmap of hashmaps, one hashmap per kind of Archetype, you might need a looser functional definition of the behavior of ArchetypeMap. Can you provide more details about how you want to implement the map of multiple types?

An easy way to improve all this is to focus more on the traits, make the traits resemble the forms of things you want to use, then just make structures to suit them afterward; then you can easily reimplement the traits on different structs later. I.E. Archetype, Entity, Component, these are traits, then TupleArchetype is a struct, MapArchetype is a struct, etc etc … the functional abstract interfaces always admit multiple structural concrete realizations.

One idea would be to make the functional lensing of the archetype map be a prototype method on the archetype class. Then instead of the component table handling all kinds of archetypes, the archetypes would insert and remove themselves from their own branches of the archetype tree. Sorry, I tried to solve this, but I am stumped about the type on the map. Hopefully this helps a little!

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! 
To provide more details about the archetype map, the actual type is a `HashMap<TypeId, Vec<u8>>` where the values are actually a memory allocation of any type. This structure allow to insert any `T` into the map, using the type id as a the key, and the type data as the value. In particular, we can fit any `ArchtypeBucket<A>` in there.
I've actually done none functionnal programming, would you recommand it to implement such an architecture ?

Comment: Yes I do recommend functional style, and here in this case I think you need a Lens<T> sort of thing, where you can address your ArchetypeMap by type. A lens could have a method to convert the given type to TypeId, fetch the data from the archetype map, and deserialize the data from the bytes to your real Archetype - try https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/07/12/thinking-in-ramda-lenses/ basically you just need a getter and a setter, here the key is a type so you can use Archetypes::<T>.get() style Turbofish to indicate your desired type of object